# How many meals to choose if I can skip some or all courses?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This question was asked in class before our professor disconnected online, trying to take a crack at it myself and would like a push in the right direction.

"A restaurant has $5$ appetizers, $6$ entrees, $3$ salads, and $7$ deserts. How many ways to choose a complete meal? How many ways to choose if I can **skip some or all** courses?"

Initially, I used the product rule to answer the first part: |$A$|= $5 * 6 * 3 * 7 = 630$

My thought process going into the second part lies along that since I can skip some or all courses, I can take the powerset of the courses, multiply the courses, then add the sums for my final answer.

For example (zero for the empty set): $P(A)$ = $0 + 5 + 6 + 3 + 7 + (5 * 6) + (5 * 3) + (5 * 7) ... $

We just started combinatorics today, so I am not sure where to head. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Your answer is almost correct.  The only error is that the empty set is still a set, so it counts as $1$, not $0$, so the sum should be $\mathbf{1}+5+6+3+7+(5 \times 6) + (5 \times 3)+ (5 \times 7) + \cdots$ ¶ However, the approach provided by the three answers is simpler.

Comment: Note that if you start with (for example) $\left[a \times b \times c \times \cdots\right]$, want to include the possibility of skipping any of the courses, but also want to add the additional constraint that you must **eat something**, then the easiest algorithm would be $$(-1) + \left[(a+1) \times (b+1) \times (c+1) \times \cdots\right].$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, for the second part, let $0$ designate that you are skipping that course.  So, instead of $a \times b \times c \times ...$ you have $(a+1) \times (b+1) \times (c+1) \times ...$

Actually unclear if this is equivalent to what you came up with.  I didn't read your query that closely.

Comment: See my comment under the OP.  It's almost the same, except they counted the empty set as $0$ sets, not $1$ set.

Answer (score 2):

HINT Treat skipping a course as another dish.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can "skip any or all courses" there are $6$ appetizers- the $5$ given **and** "no appetizer".  There are $7$ entrees- the $6$ given **and** "no entree".  There are $4$ salads, the three given **and** "no salad".  There are $8$ deserts, the $7$ given **and** "no desert".

So there are $6\times7\times4\times8$ possible means.  That would include not eating anything, eating only a desert or only an appetizer, etc,.